# dlopen fails if a wrong library has been loaded

Tags: c++, linux, qt, namespaces, dynamic-loading

I got stuck on loading my custom plugin library that links to custom shared Qt libraries that are built with a custom namespace if any system-wide Qt library has already been loaded into the process.

In other words, I have myplugin.so. It uses a few symbols from the custom Qt libs, all of these symbols differ from the respective original Qt symbols by a namespace prefix, say, myNS.
ldd on myplugin.so shows libQtCore.so.4, so it does not specify any minor Qt version.

I have done a few tests using an empty console application (that does not link to Qt) .

A. Usual plugin loading

```
dlopen("myplugin.so", RTLD_NOW);  // returns a non-null pointer, the plugin was loaded OK
```

B. Trying to load the plugin with the pre-loaded system-wide QtCore library

```
dlopen("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.7", RTLD_NOW);  // returns a non-null pointer
dlopen("myplugin.so", RTLD_NOW);  // returns a null pointer, the plugin was not loaded
```

The dlerror gives

> undefined symbol: _ZN4myNS7QObject16staticMetaObjectE

C. Trying to workaround the test B via preloading the custom QtCore library

```
dlopen("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.7", RTLD_NOW);  // returns a non-null pointer
dlopen("libQtCore.so.4.8.6", RTLD_NOW);  // custom qt library, a non-null pointer returned
dlopen("myplugin.so", RTLD_NOW);  // returns a null pointer, the plugin was not loaded
```

dlerror yields the same output.

D. Inverting the order of loading the QtCore libraries helps

```
dlopen("libQtCore.so.4.8.6", RTLD_NOW);  // custom qt library, a non-null pointer returned
dlopen("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.7", RTLD_NOW);  // returns a non-null pointer
dlopen("myplugin.so", RTLD_NOW);  // returns a non-null pointer, the plugin was loaded OK
```

According to the test C results, the loader tries to resolve symbols from the 1st loaded library, and ignores the other even though it has been loaded well.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried different combinations of the flags RTLD_NOW, RTLD_LAZY, RTLD_LOCAL, RTLD_GLOBAL, but they didn't help.

My task is to load the plugin library regardless of the other loaded Qt libraries.

Comment: I could consider using dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM... ) but it's equivocal though it loads the plugin library in any cases.

Comment: Alright, no answer. Will have to rebuild the custom Qt libs with the qtlibinfix flag.
The issue is still open.